# How to use from table without specifying in query() in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

following is my code for sqlalchemy inner join. I dont want to select any column of Order table but also I need Order as my from table.

```
query = db.session.query(Order, Customer.first_name, Customer.cnic_no, Item.name, Item.category)
query = query.join(Customer)
result = query.join(Item)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `select_from`

```
query = db.session.query(Customer.first_name, Customer.cnic_no, Item.name, Item.category)
query = query.select_from(Order)
query = query.join(Customer)
result = query.join(Item)
```